# redis cluster without replicas

Tags: kubernetes, redis, redis-cluster

Assuming I don't care to loose data, is it possible to configure a redis cluster only with masters without any replicas? That way I can scale out the processing and consume less resources.

Comment: Yes, replication is optional.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this and modify as per need it's single replicas Redis cluster however in it there is PVC to persist volume if you need you can remove that part. i am using module `ReJson` from `Redis` you can also remove it if not required.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 6379
      name: redis
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: redis
---
apiVersion: apps/v1beta2
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis  
  serviceName: redis
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis 
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: redislabs/rejson
          args: ["--requirepass", "test", "--appendonly", "yes", "--loadmodule", "/usr/lib/redis/modules/rejson.so"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
              name: redis
          resources:
            limits:
              cpu: .25
              memory: 1024Mi
            requests:
              cpu: .25
              memory: 1024Mi
          volumeMounts:
            - name: redis-volume
              mountPath: /data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: redis-volume
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```